# What is most efficient way to create new activity

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity

If i have a submenu which has three option: Create New,Update ,Manage data . what would be the best way ? create new activity for all these? create fragments? or send intent message after menu item is clicked and use if statement ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: creating new activity for each item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm replaying as an answer because I can't comment** 
I see the best practice is to create a fragment for each option and do their own operation in each of them

Comment: but why not simply changing content using if else statement? like creating layout and stuff programmatically based on condition?

Comment: You mean invisible components? Well first of all its switch statement not if else,  and you can do that but why ? Your code well be hard to understand. And also hard to design.